# Asymptotic location of zeros of of a sequence of analytic functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, asymptotics

Assume we have a sequence of functions $f_n$ analytic in a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \{ |z|\ge 1 \}$ of the complex plane, such that the sequence
$$
g_n(z) = f_n(z) - z^n
$$
converges to an analytic function $h(z)$, which has no zeros in $\Omega$. The convergence mentioned above is uniform on any compact subset of $\Omega$ (or even in the closure of $\Omega$).

The intuition says that the zeros of $f_n$ should be asymptotically close to the zeros of $z^n+h(z)$ in $\Omega$ so that they are (again, asymptotically) close to the level curves $|z|=|h(z)|^{1/n}$.

QUESTION: what formal argument can be used to justify this assertion?

To simplify it, for starters, we could even assume that $h(z)$ is a constant function.

Comment: Why would the zeros of $z^n+h(z)$ be near the zeros of $h$? Did you intend $\Omega\subset\{(|z|\le 1)\}$?

Comment: If $f_n(z)=z^n+z-2$, the hypotheses are satisfied, $g_n(z)=z-2$ converges to the analytic function $h(z)=z-2$ which has a finite number of zeros, but they aren't on $|z|=1$.

Comment: Sorry, @MichaelRenardy and Gerry Myerson, trying to maximally simplify the statement, I omitted one important moment. So, I just modified the setup to make it even simpler. I assume that the limiting function $h$ does not vanish in $\Omega$. Then the zeros of $f_n$ should be close to the zeros of $z^n+h(z)$, and in $\Omega$, they must satisfy $|z|=|h(z)|^{1/n}$.

Comment: How about $f_n(z)=z^n-z-1/n$, $h(z)=-z$, $\Omega=\{z\colon|z|>1\}$? Then $z^n+h(z)$ has no zeroes in $\Omega$, but $f_n(z)$ does.

Comment: It is a good example, @IosifPinelis, thanks, but it is still true that the zeros of $f_n$ are close to the circle $|z|=|h(z)|^{1/n}=1$, although this line is on the boundary of the domain. I agree that the zeros can escape to the boundary, but the point of my question is, what is the format argument supporting the assertion that they are close to the mentioned level lines?

Comment: If $h\not\equiv 0$ you can say nothing about zeros of $f_n-z^n$ except that they "escape" from $\Omega$, which means that  every compact $K\subset\Omega$ contains none of them, when $n$ is large enough. If $h\equiv 0$ you can say nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexandreEremenko, but my question is about the zeros of $f_n$, not the zeros of $f_n(z)-z^n$. I still think that the zeros of $f_n$ should be asymptotically close to the zeros of $z^n + h(z)$, assuming, of course, that $h\not \equiv 0$.

Comment: Thet are asymptotically close to zeros of $z^n+h(z)$ assuming that $z^n+h(z)\not\equiv 0$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I totally agree with that, but what is the formal argument that I can use to prove it?

Comment: The formal argument is called the Caratheodory theorem: if $f_n\to f\not\equiv 0$, then zeros of $f_n$ tend to zeros of $f$. The proof consists of the application of the argument principle.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, sorry to disagree. Caratheodory theorem only tells me that, in this case, the zeros of $f_n(z)-z^n$ tend to the zeros of $h$ (which are none), but doesn't tell me much about the zeros of $f_n$. Am I right, or am I missing something?